# Internal navigation rejected: <allow-navigation not set> in Cordova on iOS

Tags: html, ios, cordova, web, cordova-plugins

I have built an iOS app using Cordova. The app tries to load a web page e.g. `http://yourdomain.example/home` in index.html. But, the page stays white blank with error in console "Internal navigation rejected - `<allow-navigation>` not set for `URL='http://yourdomain.example/home'"`.

I have already set `<access origin="http://yourdomain.example/home" subdomains="true" />` and also tried by setting `<allow-navigation>` tag. But the page stays blank. am I missing anything else? Please guide.

After adding the following meta tag in `index.html`, the "internal navigation error" has gone, but the page is still white blank.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script src: 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

Answer (score 87, accepted):

I was having this problem and it turns out there are two config.xml files. The first one is in Xcode, but you have to edit the second one from the filesystem.

```
AppName/config.xml

AppName/platforms/ios/AppName/config.xml
```

I added

```
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

to both of them and it worked. Using 6.3.0.

Comment: This answer is not right, you have to modify only the root config.xml, then when you do a cordova prepare, build or run it will be copied to the other config.xml

Comment: I don't use cordova prepare, I open the project in Xcode because I've made customizations.

Comment: Tom Kincaids answer worked for me perfectly! For some reason cordove removes the line from AppName/platforms/ios/AppName/config.xml after very build, even though I added it to AppName/config.xml.
So it looks like I have to manually add this line after every build

Answer (score 27):

You have to add this line to your `config.xml`

```
<allow-navigation href="http://yourdomain.example/home" />
```

or this one if you want to allow the navigation to all the URLs on `yourdomain.example`

```
<allow-navigation href="http://yourdomain.example/*" />
```

Comment: I have tried this, but did not work. Do I need to install some plugin for this to work?

Comment: If you use cordova-ios 4.x.x you don't have to add anything else. Try with `<allow-navigation href="*" />` and removing the Content-Security-Policy tag

Comment: Mine is a Cordova project. I have two 'config.xml' files. One in beside 'www/' folder and another is inside 'www/' folder. It worked for me if I change the 'config.xml' which is outside the 'www/' folder.

Comment: You should't have a config.xml inside the www folder

Comment: Refer to my answer if you are using Ionic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38065902/ionic-2-cli-command-ionic-emulate-ios-livereload-not-working-on-ios-9/38493229#38493229

Comment: Hey any one help me.. i will get this bellow error ionic cordova application play youtube video.  ERROR Internal navigation rejected - <allow-navigation> not set for url='http://www.youtube.com/embed/

Comment: Try with `<allow-navigation href="*" />`

Answer (score 8):

It is a scheme used internally, just allow access/navigation to it:

```
<access origin="about:*" />
<allow-navigation href="about:" />
```

It is not recommended to use

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

as described in [cordova-plugin-whitelist](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/).

Answer (score 8):

Thanks for the pointer. The solution

```
<allow-navigation href="about:" />
```

caused a cordova prepare error for me. I need to use the following instead:

```
<allow-navigation href="about:*" />
```

Answer (score 6):

It's not recommend to open a url in your base web view. Use the cordova-plugin-inappbrowser and call the inappbrowser to open outer url:

```
function open_outer_url(url){
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.InAppBrowser){
        window.cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, "_blank", 'location=no');
    }else{
        window.open(url,'_blank');
    }
}
```

Comment: Some use of iframes triggers the 'internal navigation' security restriction. So even a well-behaved SPA might need to enable this.

Comment: // 'hybrid' detects both Cordova and Capacitor https://ionicframework.com/docs/core-concepts/cross-platform //  if (this.platform.is('hybrid')) { }