# IOS - cordova inappbrowser error, cant show the webpages from iframe

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, iframe

try to remove the secure addres but not solved. and already install plugin inappbrowser latest but not solved.

please advise ..

this is the error code in console log:

```
2016-06-03 11:20:44.157 thetestflight[4642:351202] Resetting plugins due to page load.
2016-06-03 11:20:45.467 thetestflight[4642:351202] Finished load of: 
file:///Users/solution/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/EF2995F3-CB8E-4C20-BAA0-C096F15F920F/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/E652A38C-EB46-4241-B8F6-31490C21A5A8/ManNa%20Korea.app/www/page-2337.html
2016-06-03 11:20:45.864 thetestflight[4642:351202] THREAD WARNING: ['File'] took '20.331787' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
2016-06-03 11:34:20.603 thetestflight[4642:351202] ERROR Internal navigation rejected - <allow-navigation> not set for url='https://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fmannakorea.sg&width&height=558&colorscheme=light&show_faces=true&header=false&stream=true&show_border=false'
2016-06-03 11:34:20.615 thetestflight[4642:351202] CDVWebViewDelegate: Navigation started when state=1
2016-06-03 11:34:20.615 thetestflight[4642:351202] Failed to load webpage with error: CDVWebViewDelegate: Navigation started when state=1
```

thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36234957/internal-navigation-rejected-allow-navigation-not-set-in-cordova-on-ios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the [cordova whitelist plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist)?

If not install it and put this in your config.xml

```
<access origin="*"/>
<access origin="tel:*" launch-external="yes"/>
<allow-navigation href="*"/>
<allow-navigation href="http://*/*"/>
<allow-navigation href="https://*/*"/>
<allow-navigation href="data:*"/>
<allow-intent href="*"/>
<access origin="*"/>
```

Comment: The whitelist plugin should be added by default to the `config.xml`. `<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1"`

Comment: Mark should you have <access origin="*"/> in there twice?