# Ionic 2 cli command " ionic emulate ios --livereload" not working on iOs 9

Tags: angular, ios-simulator, ionic2, livereload

So I am trying out Ionic 2. I found out this Ionic Cli command does not work:

```
ionic emulate ios --livereload
```

or

```
ionic emulate ios --lc
```

It show "Setup Live Reload" in the log but the app just hang in the opening splash screen. Can not find further error in the log (no error output), but the whole thing is frozen. It work without the -lc flag. So if I just run

```
ionic emulate ios
```

It works and the app launch. Anyone know a workaround for this? I am on iOs 9.3.

Comment: Did you figure out a solution for this? I am running into same issue in xcode and the below solution doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same issue and these are the steps I followed:

1. Open the root folder of the app.
2. Find `config.xml` file.
3. Look for the line `<allow-navigation href="" />`
4. Change it to `<allow-navigation href="http://YOUR_IP_ADDRESS:8100/" />` and save. Eg. `<allow-navigation href="http://192.168.118.25:8100/" />`
5. Now run the `ionic emulate ios -lcs` command again.

This time it should work perfectly on your simulator.

Comment: the application loads, but the changes at the code are not reloaded.

Comment: does not solve the problem for me. Livereload still does not work for me on ios or android after this.

Answer (score 0):

excute `ionic address first`
then excute `ionic emulate ios --livereload` 
after some step, you have to choose a IP. Choose what ever you want and it will work!