# navigation rejected - <allow-navigation> not set for url='gap://ready'

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ios-simulator

I have developed ionic app, which runs on android and browser very well now i am running on ios.   when i run app on simulator, app start and show first( ionic symbol page) constantly, and remains as it is.

I checked log,

i found the error `Internal navigation rejected: <allow-navigation not set>`  as answered in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36234957/internal-navigation-rejected-allow-navigation-not-set-in-cordova-on-ios) i followed the `<allow-navigation href="*" />`

but in next run i got the new error as,

```
navigation rejected - <allow-navigation> not set for url='gap://ready'
```

can anyone tell me what it is exact `gap://ready`

my logcat as,

```
    2018-02-15 08:53:26.667295-0500 MyApp[25051:947093] DiskCookieStorage changing policy from 2 to 0, cookie file: file:///Users/madhur/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/10AB7D02-82BE-48D5-9F7A-8E32C7522FD1/data/Containers/Data/Application/5988B7DB-8F18-4213-B611-F6C2E076577F/Library/Cookies/com.cmsbiyani.binarycookies
2018-02-15 08:53:26.967945-0500 MyApp[25051:947093] Apache Cordova native platform version 4.5.3 is starting.
2018-02-15 08:53:26.969058-0500 MyApp[25051:947093] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2018-02-15 08:53:27.016616-0500 MyApp[25051:947093] CDVWKWebViewEngine: trying to inject XHR polyfill
2018-02-15 08:53:27.313401-0500 MyApp[25051:947093] [MC] Lazy loading NSBundle MobileCoreServices.framework
2018-02-15 08:53:27.324135-0500 MyApp[25051:947093] [MC] Loaded MobileCoreServices.framework
2018-02-15 08:53:30.288878-0500 MyApp[25051:947093] CDVWKWebViewEngine will reload WKWebView if required on resume
2018-02-15 08:53:30.289800-0500 MyApp[25051:947093] Using Ionic WKWebView
2018-02-15 08:53:30.292733-0500 MyApp[25051:947093] [CDVTimer][console] 0.328064ms
2018-02-15 08:53:30.294557-0500 MyApp[25051:947093] [CDVTimer][handleopenurl] 0.702024ms
2018-02-15 08:53:30.302675-0500 MyApp[25051:947093] [CDVTimer][intentandnavigationfilter] 7.043958ms
2018-02-15 08:53:30.303247-0500 MyApp[25051:947093] [CDVTimer][gesturehandler] 0.195026ms
2018-02-15 08:53:30.398290-0500 MyApp[25051:947093] [CDVTimer][splashscreen] 94.652057ms
2018-02-15 08:53:30.398900-0500 MyApp[25051:947093] [CDVTimer][uniquedeviceid] 0.187039ms
2018-02-15 08:53:30.404529-0500 MyApp[25051:947093] [CDVTimer][keyboard] 5.079985ms
2018-02-15 08:53:30.405271-0500 MyApp[25051:947093] [CDVTimer][TotalPluginStartup] 112.934947ms
2018-02-15 08:53:30.439021-0500 MyApp[25051:947093] DidFinishLaunchingWithOptions
2018-02-15 08:53:30.678659-0500 MyApp[25051:947337] 4.9.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Firebase Analytics v.40009000 started
2018-02-15 08:53:30.682557-0500 MyApp[25051:947337] 4.9.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled 
2018-02-15 08:53:30.887251-0500 MyApp[25051:947391] 4.9.0 - [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM001000] FIRMessaging Remote Notifications proxy enabled, will swizzle remote notification receiver handlers. If you'd prefer to manually integrate Firebase Messaging, add "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled" to your Info.plist, and set it to NO. Follow the instructions at:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#method_swizzling_in_firebase_messaging
to ensure proper integration.
2018-02-15 08:53:30.889898-0500 MyApp[25051:947093] createNotificationChecker
2018-02-15 08:53:30.890256-0500 MyApp[25051:947093] not coldstart
2018-02-15 08:53:31.083992-0500 MyApp[25051:947093] Unexpected call to didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError, ignoring: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3010 "remote notifications are not supported in the simulator" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=remote notifications are not supported in the simulator}
2018-02-15 08:53:31.112584-0500 MyApp[25051:947093] app become active
2018-02-15 08:53:31.142949-0500 MyApp[25051:947093] active
2018-02-15 08:53:31.148885-0500 MyApp[25051:947093] PushPlugin skip clear badge
2018-02-15 08:53:31.546226-0500 MyApp[25051:947389] TIC Read Status [1:0x0]: 1:57
2018-02-15 08:53:31.546449-0500 MyApp[25051:947389] TIC Read Status [1:0x0]: 1:57
2018-02-15 08:53:32.087448-0500 MyApp[25051:947337] 4.9.0 - [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM012002] Error in application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: remote notifications are not supported in the simulator
2018-02-15 08:53:33.802288-0500 MyApp[25051:947093] app become active
2018-02-15 08:53:33.803760-0500 MyApp[25051:947093] active
2018-02-15 08:53:33.804472-0500 MyApp[25051:947093] PushPlugin skip clear badge
2018-02-15 08:53:34.106383-0500 MyApp[25051:947093] InstanceID token: eMNbF4IglXM:APA91bGDe2LC_9L3GBc-gSbbCuoTAc2U7TNwcZbRRkQXEQ5gIlAho2eh33Ga4YUobzxfodvPubzE2oU1g75fwoPlgBGCmAAhh_M8_4F6fU2CZE7LSYcznM8gs_uuyu8QPUUyK65MqB3c
2018-02-15 08:53:34.308040-0500 MyApp[25051:947093] Connected to FCM.
2018-02-15 08:53:45.704630-0500 MyApp[25051:947093] ERROR Internal navigation rejected - <allow-navigation> not set for url='gap://ready'
2018-02-15 08:53:45.791635-0500 MyApp[25051:947093] FCMPlugin.js: is created
2018-02-15 08:53:45.798957-0500 MyApp[25051:947093] Ionic Native: deviceready event fired after 3094 ms
2018-02-15 08:53:45.799765-0500 MyApp[25051:947093] Cordova view ready
2018-02-15 08:53:45.806069-0500 MyApp[25051:947093] FCMPlugin Ready OK
2018-02-15 08:53:46.754941-0500 MyApp[25051:947834] TIC Read Status [6:0x0]: 1:57
2018-02-15 08:53:46.755146-0500 MyApp[25051:947834] TIC Read Status [6:0x0]: 1:57
2018-02-15 08:53:46.984248-0500 MyApp[25051:947834] TIC Read Status [7:0x0]: 1:57
2018-02-15 08:53:46.984512-0500 MyApp[25051:947834] TIC Read Status [7:0x0]: 1:57
2018-02-15 08:57:31.269002-0500 MyApp[25051:956884] TIC Read Status [2:0x0]: 1:57
2018-02-15 08:57:31.269657-0500 MyApp[25051:956884] TIC Read Status [2:0x0]: 1:57
2018-02-15 08:57:33.794992-0500 MyApp[25051:957714] TIC Read Status [3:0x0]: 1:57
2018-02-15 08:57:33.795472-0500 MyApp[25051:957714] TIC Read Status [3:0x0]: 1:57
2018-02-15 08:57:34.947096-0500 MyApp[25051:957819] TIC Read Status [5:0x0]: 1:57
2018-02-15 08:57:34.947301-0500 MyApp[25051:957819] TIC Read Status [5:0x0]: 1:57
```

Answer (score 1):

*'gap'* is required on iOS when using UIWebView and is needed for js/native communications.
This tag must be added on index.html over meta tag content-security-policy.

You can make double click of this information on https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/#content-security-policy and https://content-security-policy.com/ and https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview/1617943-gapbetweenpages, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview